# SayNumber() function for asterisk for different languages

Tags: numbers, asterisk, audio

I am using asterisk 11.0 and want to use SayNumber() function to speak the number in hindi(Indian language) .I have searched a bit and [found](http://www.asteriskmakeeasy.com/2014/01/asterisk-sayconf-format-for-hindi-and.html?m=1) code for it. I have pasted the code in say.conf.

My problem is that i have only en(sound file in english) folder on my sounds folder and i need to install the hindi sound folder.Can i install hindi sound file now or i have to make menuselect again?

Is there anything more i need to play number in hindi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this page

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sound+files+international

and this one

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sound+files

Also you have set language for channel used(for sip in sip.conf)